# get block that has been instantiated earlier

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, event-observer

I want to get and modify the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` block from within an observer which is listening for the event `resource_get_tablename`.

In my observer I'm using the code

```
if($observer->getTableName() == 'sales_flat_order_grid') {
    $block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('Sales_Order_Grid');
}
```

Whilst this does get an instance of `Sales_Order_Grid` its not the one that has already been instantiated by the system.

I added some logging to the constructor of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` and I can see that its called twice. I hadn't expected this behaviour as the word Singleton, in the `getBlockSingleton` method, to me implies that there will be only one instance stored in the registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBlockSingleton('Sales_Order_Grid')` will return the same instance on every call, but it will **not** return a block previously instantiated by other means (i.e. not as a singleton).

There are very little valid use cases for `getBlockSingleton()` and you should not use it for regular blocks in the layout hierarchy. I'd even argue to never use it at all.

To refer an existing block in the layout, you have to know its *name*, not its *class*. Then you can use

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock($name);
```

In your case, the name is probably [`sales.order.grid`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml#L32). This name in the XML is for AJAX requests only, but the name for the automatically created grid block should be [the same](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php#L66). You can also use template hints to find out block names.

Comment: Template hints didn't help get the block name, so I used $block->getNameInLayout() withing the block in question. Turns out it was called "sales_order.grid". Thank you.